# how to handle multiple messages at once - telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, telepot

I built a telegram bot using telepot that sand big amount of photos. (between 100 - 200 pics)

and I got a problem that if multiple users ask the bot for photos at the same time the bot will start sending the first request and then go to the second request and it goes on like this.

Is there a way to change the way the bot handles the request to answer multiple users at the same time?

```
def handle(msg):
   if message == '/send_pics':
      for photo in photos 
          # loop that send photos to the user

MessageLoop(bot, handle).run_as_thread()

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
```

That a simplify description  of the bot i made.
If you got any idea for a way to handle muliple messages at the same time i would love to hear it

Comment: I suggest using the [async version](https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#async-version-python-3-5). I personally prefer working with [aiogram](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram) which is asynchronous by default